# Php encrypt paypal button

Tags: php, ssl, paypal

First of all i have read paypal documentation etc.
I found this example for php [Link](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php). 
I am wondering whether this works fine because i read here that some people are having problems. Also is it possible to use http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php this library in order to not call exec?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you encounter actual problems?

Comment: *"i read here that some people are having problems"* Which would actually apply to many stuff, but you should more care about yourself than other people. Please don't ask such type of questions, I mean, do you know if that encryption still works when the sun clashes with venus?

Comment: I don't know why people closed this question. People are mean sometimes? I understood you I think, but it would help if you reworded it to be more clear. You're trying to use APIs with PHP to encrypt a paypal button. I came up with a workaround that's far, far easier here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14489512/105539

Answer (score 1):

Just for future googlers.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

There is Website Payment standars. It provides code for php using openssl!